# If random rotations are included in the data augmentation process, how are the new bounding boxes calculated?

Tags: deep-learning, object-detection, object-recognition, yolo, data-augmentation

When studying bounding box-based detectors, it's not clear to me if data augmentation includes adding random rotations.

If random rotations are added, how is the new bounding box calculated?

Comment: I don't have much practical experience with them, but, I guess, if you rotate the images, you just need to rotate the boxes (i.e. labels) too. Check [this](https://github.com/anhtuan85/Data-Augmentation-for-Object-Detection/blob/master/augmentation.ipynb) (which may not be a reliable implementation: I don't know!).

Comment: The problem is the predicted boxes are not rotated - so would you just create a new box from the rotated images bounding box corners? This works but might make the predicted box a little larger,.